# He said he "had played"/"played" golf yesterday

Tags: difference, past-tense, past-perfect

What is the difference when using the past simple and the past perfect tense, in this sentence?

> He said he **had played** golf yesterday.
>
> He said he **played** golf yesterday.

Comment: Google: stackexchange past tense past perfect tense

Comment: Because of the word ***yesterday***, there's little scope for any difference in meaning. In the unlikely event that speaker is refuting someone else who's just claimed that the person being spoken of ***didn't*** play golf yesterday, he almost certainly use the first (Past Perfect) version - simply so he could stress the word ***had*** for emphasis. Without ***yesterday***, there are a number of other possible meanings, not all of which can be conveyed equally by both versions.